# android login from ios web service?

Tags: php, android, ios, web-services

I'm attempting to connect an `Android` app to a web service originally designed for `iOS` and I'm not sure if it's going to be possible. I also did not design this web service so I am looking through this code that isn't mine and just kind of fumbling around. The current web service is written in `PHP` and uses `SOAP` and `WSDL`. If i can connect to this web service I will attempt to use `ksoap2` unless I find a better alternative. I will be using a lot of links in this post because without them you will be looking at an obnoxious amount of code.

So anyways here is the problem in a nutshell. I have this list for the web service url's 
[URL List](http://pastebin.com/yhcXxNJc) 
and from the looks of that list I need to make my login request to **iphoneview/iphone_get_details.php** which has this inside of it. 
[get_details](http://pastebin.com/8vv1Vvxj)
however when I use this code

```
class LogMeIn extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(
            "http://www.fakesite.com/myv2/iphoneview/iphone_get_details.php");

    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        try {
            username = un.getText().toString();
            password = pw.getText().toString();
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(
                    2);
            nameValuePairs
                    .add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
            nameValuePairs
                    .add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            String res = inputStream(response.getEntity().getContent())
                    .toString();
            Log.v("RESPONSE", res);

            // if username and password are valid, launch main activity
            if (res.toString() == "1") {
                Intent logIn = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        Main.class);
                startActivity(logIn);
            }
            // send the user a message saying the login failed
            else {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        pw.setText("");
                        fail.setText(R.string.fail);
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

    }
}
```

all I get back is this for a response

```
05-25 13:57:21.292: V/RESPONSE(5871): <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC '-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN' 'http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd'><plist version='1.0'><dict><key>iId</key><string>0</string><key>itemChildren</key><array></array></dict></plist>
```

I know where this response is coming from, there very bottom of the **iphoneview/iphone_get_details.php**. The problem is I don't know if it's because

1. I need to be wrapping this in a `SOAP` request
2. I can't use this code
3. I'm connecting to the wrong file (doubt it)
4. all of the above and/or something else

Now common sense tells me from looking at the current iphone_get_details.php file that I will not be receiving a response of "1" or "true" either way. As a matter of fact that file looks like it sends back a ton of information, when in essence all I want is a "1" or a "true" to make sure I'm properly connected with the correct login information. So if anyone has the time to look this question over I'd be grateful, I understand it's a lot of reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC '-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN'http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd'>
<plist version='1.0'>
<dict>
    <key>iId</key>
    <string>0</string>
    <key>itemChildren</key>
    <array></array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

If you're going to examine the result, the `iId` is `0`, it could mean that the `iId` is set to zero if the username and password does not exist, coz initially, `ids's` starts with 1 or it could be that the `iId` of the user in the database is `0` by then you can say the the username and password matched in the database and would mean the password and username provided by the user is correct or the other way around.

edited:::

I have checked your link here http://pastebin.com/8vv1Vvxj and based on the code and the xml returned, it signifies that the default value of `iId` is `0` if there are no matched username and password, otherwise if the `iId` is not 0 meaning the username and password is correct.

initial values in php

```
$vUserName      = stripslashes(trim($_REQUEST["txtUser"]));
$vPassword      = stripslashes(trim($_REQUEST["txtPass"]));

$returnFinalString      = "";
$member_id = 0;

.
.
.
//if this condition is true, meaning, the username and password matched and exist
if(mysql_num_rows($member_res)>0){
   $member_id  = $mem_row['user_id'];
}
 //and the $member_id is changed to non-zero
```

and for the result, you just have to parse the xml returned and get the `iId` value and check if it's 0 or not, by then you can determine if the user can be logged in or not.

Comment: the result is part of the problem, but it's minor. I could handle an actual response regardless of what it was. I don't think this is a response to my POST at all though, I think it's just a response because a non iOS mobile device is trying to access this information.

Comment: thank you for all your hard work. I have decided to just create my own web service. In the long run it will be much easier to update/maintain anyways. Answer accepted, bounty will be awarded tomorrow when the timer is up

Comment: Your welcome, yah, it's good if you will be the one to create your own webservice, it's easier to understand and can save you much time. :)

Answer (score 1):

Some pointers - you might consider using Robospice and then parsing the response into Java POJO's using Android Spring and the SimpleXML message converter.  The response you are getting back is the XML for an iphone plist, which is going to be challenging to work with in the Android environment, but not impossible.  The response from the server has nothing to do with your Android code, so you should be able to verify that it's the same as what gets sent to the iPhone app by using a web browser.

Hopefully this gives you some places to look and some forward momentum.

Comment: That is unfortunate news. I was really hoping I would be able to use this code. My gut told me exactly what you just posted though. Well I've spent a week messing with this. I need to just bite the bullet and write my own PHP for this app then. In my opinion it will be quicker, especially when dealing with testing/debugging. I will wait a bit to see if anyone else has a different response, otherwise I'm going to accept this answer and just move on with my life